# My alernative to nested sets for arbitrary-depth hierarchical data sets: Good or Bad?

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, hierarchy, traversal

While recreating my CMS, I wanted an alternative to the traditional parent/child approach for managing the sitemap / page hierarchy.  I had remembered seeing the nested set model a while back, but couldn't remember what it was called.  So, I stumbled upon a similar approach that I want to evaluate and compare the properties, making sure I won't run into dumb limitations later on because I didn't go with what is already time-tested.  So, please advise if A) it's already been invented (what's it called?!), B) there are fundamental flaws in the properties, or C) it's a good approach (please give good justification!).

Consider this list:

- Home

  - About Us
  - Contact Us
  - Products

    - Clothing
    - Books
    - Electronics
  - Knowledge Base
  - Other stuff

Under the nested set model, I believe you store the left/right descriptors for each node with a depth-first traversal:

```
Home                  1-18
    About Us          2-3
    Contact Us        4-5
    Products          6-13
        Clothing      7-8
        Books         9-10
        Electronics  11-12
    Knowledge Base   14-15
    Other stuff      16-17
```

And here's my "wrong way" that I'm starting to like better:

```
Home                  1-9
    About Us          2-2
    Contact Us        3-3
    Products          4-7
        Clothing      5-5
        Books         6-6
        Electronics   7-7
    Knowledge Base    8-8
    Other stuff       9-9
```

Rather than a left/right pair, I'm storing ID and LAST_CONTAINED_ID.  I found that many of the properties are the same (or very similar):

- The root node is ID = 1
- For "leaves," both properties are equal, while with branches, they are not
- The total number of "subnodes" for any given node is LAST_CONTAINED_ID - ID
- All contained nodes have an ID > the container's ID, but <= the container's LAST_CONTAINED_ID
- The ancestor nodes have an ID < the child ID, but also a LAST_CONTAINED_ID >= the child ID
- The depth is the SUM of the ancestor nodes

In addition, the ID serves an order-specific, unique identifier (with no gaps!).  I've found it easier also to store DEPTH and PARENT references for simplicity, but that's pretty much the same for nested sets too from what I understand.

So, does this count as a nested set?  And is it already a common approach (but why hadn't I heard of it before...)?  Is there a good reason why I should use a true nested set over this?

I welcome your thoughts.

Comment: FYI, the nested set model is a way of having a single table in an RDBMS store all the information needed for a hierarchy of an unknown depth (i.e. an infinite list without recursion): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model#Example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only advantage it gives is the 'no gaps' feature, but to achieve that you've had to change the logic applied to right-values.  In the original model, you get the children of 'Products' by seeing all those values 6 < .. < 13, but in your model, you get those children by seeing values 4 < .. <= 7.  Having to treat right-values different to left-values makes it slightly less elegant.
Another minor gripe is that in the original, the jump from 12 to 14 highlights that you've changed level, whereas in your model you don't get such visual cues.
So if you're happy using (<, <=) in place of (<, <) then it works.  (Since it appears to be equivalent, I can't say 'good' or 'bad', but you've already highlighted the dangers of implementing the path less travelled.)

Comment: I think you're right about the jump from 12-14. I believe that it's true (in usual nested sets), that for any node `n1`, if there is a node, `n2`, with `n1.right+1`==`n2.left` then `n2` is the next sibling (and similarly for going left), which is lost in this new model.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! (Though, I was hoping to get more feedback, but this is helpful.)

Comment: I have found a few more properties I like, such adjusting the values on insert/delete at a particular index is very straightforward.  Deleting a branch will actually move all children up a level by default (which is a nice alternative to cascading deletes for a traditional parent-child foreign key setup).  I think can live without the nextSibling() simplicity.